# TimeoutException - Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, timeoutexception

I would appreciate some help: it finds an element with this XPATH:

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '100')]")`

However, when clicking I get the ElementNotInteractableException. Then, I try to solve it like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '100')]")))
element.click()
```

Then, I get TimeoutException that I cannot solve. Thank you very much in advance.

This is the DOM where it is inserted:

```
<div class="mat-menu-content ng-tns-c83-207">
 <div _ngcontent-xpe-c205="" class="option info-f12-w400-space-gray600 cursor-pointer ng-tns-c83-207">
   <div _ngcontent-xpe-c205="" class="value selected ng-star-inserted"> 25 </div>
   <div _ngcontent-xpe-c205="" class="value ng-star-inserted">50</div>
   <div _ngcontent-xpe-c205="" class="value ng-star-inserted"> 100 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share a link to the page you are working on and ALL your code?

Comment: hi, sorry, it is a private web, thank you very much!

Comment: The element did not become clickable within the given time limit.  Are you sure that element should be clickable?

Comment: Is that locator unique? In that element in a visible screen area?

Comment: after running this code: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '100')]") I get this result as it finds the element: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cda1ae809bd4b60d4e7ca4ee5aa1d762", element="c639e395-e174-45f9-9b07-b8521aa48473")>

Comment: It is the only element with text '100' in this UI, but is is in a pop up so I think when clicking it it miss other buttons below (it is a complex DOM in angular, no id and I tried several paths with no success)

Comment: OK, there is such element on the page, but it can be hidden etc.

Comment: The element was not clickable.  That means it was disabled, hidden, located behind another element, etc.  Since you can't share the source code, that's really all we can do to help.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function it will give you the element if it ready else you will get None

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
def find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath, delay=5):
    delay = delay  # seconds
    xpath_referrers = xpath
    try:
        my_elem = WebDriverWait(self.browser, delay).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_referrers)))
        return my_elem
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"cant find elem at {delay} delay times ")
        return None
```